# How to pass values between property files

Tags: spring-boot, properties, yaml

I've two configuration files, application.yml and myConfig.properties. How do I pass a values from myConfig.properties and set to application.yml?

I've tried wrapping in `${property_name_from_other_file`} but I'm getting:

> Failed to bind properties under 'server.port' to java.lang.Integer:
>   Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to java.lang.Integer

Here is the content of `application.yml`

```
server.port=${dev.server.port}
```

Here is the content of `myConfig.properties`

```
dev.server.port=8400
```

Comment: Are you really mixing yml and properties? And shouldn't it throw because your yml isn't yml?

Comment: @bambam thanks for responding. I'm being able to fetch String values from properties file without an exception.But fetching Integer value is the issue.